# Create table structure from query output

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, timestamp

I am in need of SQL that will create a table structure based on the query with one specified DateTime column

Input:
Query:

```
    select studentname, student_id from mytable name
```

ColumnName:
"MyTimeSTamp"
"TableName"

It should create a table called "TableName" with following columns:

```
MyTimeSTamp  
studentname  
student_id
```

Comment: a real table or a temp table?

Comment: Result of the input query should be put into the schema of the new table?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
select getdate() MyTimeSTamp, studentname, student_id
into TableName from mytable name
```